# definition $\epsilon$ de $\limsup_{t\to+\infty}$

Tags: limits, limsup-and-liminf

Please what is the $\epsilon$ definition of this limit $$\limsup_{t\to+\infty}\frac{|f(t)|}{|t| |g(t)|}<+\infty$$

is it $$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists A>0,\forall t\in\mathbb{R}, |t|>A\Rightarrow |f(t)|<\varepsilon |t| |g(t)| +\ell$$

thank you

Comment: Close : needs two refinements.  [1] Since the limit is as $t \to +\infty$ rather than as $|t| \to +\infty,~$ I regard your distinction around $|t|$ inappropriate.  As $t \to +\infty$, $t$ is always positive.  [2] In general, if given a Limit $L$ of a function $h(t)$, the definition is : $$\forall \epsilon > 0 ~~\exists ~\text{Real Number} ~R > 0 ~\text{such that} ~t > R \implies |h(t) - L| < \epsilon.$$

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, not quite. Here's a definition. There exists an $l$ such that for every $\varepsilon > 0$ there exists $M$ such that $t > M$ implies
$$
\frac{|f(t)|}{|t||g(t)|} < l + \varepsilon
$$
and for infinitely many $t$,
$$
\frac{|f(t)|}{|t||g(t)|} > l - \varepsilon
$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\forall \varepsilon>0, \exists B > 0, \forall A > B, \exists t>A,|t||g(t)|(\ell-\varepsilon) < |f(t)|< |t| |g(t)| (\ell + \epsilon)$$